# NSIS MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT not showing

Tags: installation, nsis

NSIS newbie here. Using nsis v2.51 with MUI2 (Modern UI 2)

As stated, my problem is that even though I set the `MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT` define, the resulting installer does not show any text at all where it should be. The same happens for `MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT`. However, page specific text defines show correctly.

This is the minimal NSIS script that demonstrates the issue:

```
Name "Just for show"
OutFile "MuiText.exe"

!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "AAAAAAA"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "CHANGE MEEEEEEE! CHANGE MEEEEEEE!!!!"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Please select the directory where you  want this fine program installed." 
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Enter Directory"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

Section
SectionEnd
```

And this is the screenshot of the resulting installer:

[image: Notice the empty header]

Any ideas on how can I make the text show up? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify at least one language with MUI_LANGUAGE otherwise the UI does not work correctly:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "AAAAAAA"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "CHANGE MEEEEEEE! CHANGE MEEEEEEE!!!!"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Please select the directory where you  want this fine program installed." 
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Enter Directory"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```